# Denominator doubled

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics

Originally $a = 12 \space m/s$, then $r$ is doubled. Find the new value for $a$. $a = v^2/r$. If I am right, $v$ is originally $6$ which then turns to $36$ so if you divide it by $3$ it gives you $12$. Later if you double $r$, it would be $6$ which the final answer would be $6$.

Comment: What part is task, what part is yours?

Comment: This is not clear.  If by $a$ you are referring to acceleration then your units are wrong.  And what is $r$?  Are you  talking about acceleration around a circle?  Are you keeping speed constant?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your answer as your formula for $a$ is currently ambiguous. But if $a$ is inversely proportional to $r$ and then $r$ is doubled, then $a$ will halve to give $6$.

Answer (score 0):

You're right.

Since $a=v^2/r$, $a$ is inversely proportional to $r$.

Doubling $r$ halves $a$, and $6\text{ }m/s^2$ is half of $12\text{ }m/s^2.$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $v$ stays constant,
$$ar = v^2 = k$$
where $k$ is a constant. So $a$ and $r$ are inversely proportional. If $r$ is doubled, $a$ is halved, and the new acceleration is $$\frac12(12\frac{m}{s^2})=6 \frac{m}{s^2}$$